# regarding using dtype.newbyteorder

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I once read the following function in a given program, but I am not very clear about what is this function used for? According `SciPy.org`,

> dtype.newbyteorder(new_order='S')
>   Return a new dtype with a different byte order.

I do not quite understand what does it mean?

```
def _read32(bytestream):
   dt = numpy.dtype(numpy.uint32).newbyteorder('>')
   return numpy.frombuffer(bytestream.read(4), dtype=dt)[0]
```

Comment: It might help if you read about "endianess": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype(np.uint32)
>>> val = np.frombuffer(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04', dtype=dt)
>>> hex(val)
'0x4030201'
>>> val2 = np.frombuffer(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04', dtype=dt.newbyteorder('>'))
>>> hex(val2)
'0x1020304'
```

Byte order describes which order to pack a series of bytes (in this case, a `bytes` object from a `b"..."` literal) into the data type you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function I listed above is used to retrieve an image. It seems to me that we can control the byte order when we read the image. But how we can know which should be the correct byte order?

Comment: @user288609: You shouldn't care - the pixel values in an image are all bytes (usually), so byte order is not a concern (try the above code with `uint8`, and you'll see what I mean). However, you now need to know whether the image is BGR or RGB. The only way to know that is look at the program that wrote it!